# Using `pass` as column name with SqlAlchemy on existing database? Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, keyword

I have an existing database, in which one of the tables has the name `pass`, which unfortunaitly in Python is a keyword. Hew can I manage to create a proper Insert statement? For now, I have somthing like this:

```
stmt = db.insert(users).values(
            pass='new password`
        )
```

Comment: You can pass a dict to `values` eg `values({'pass': 'new password'})`